# How can i fully customize sidebar_menu in django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, customization

I don't know any way how can I overright sidebar_menu.html or create some progress to customize it.

so can i get some hits what can i do for coustomize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override many of the templates which the admin module uses to generate the various pages of an admin site. You can even override a few of these templates for a specific app, or a specific model.

Read the Docs of Django. e.g.
[Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Comment: yes, I got it after asking the question.